# How to use more arguments when calling functions?

Tags: c++

Sorry, I know this is really basic, but I don't know how to search it the proper way, so here we go.
I'm trying to call MessageBoxA, and I want the message to replace '%s' with something else. Example:

```
MessageBoxA(0, TEXT("You have %s items"), "title", 0);
```

Can anyone help me? And once again, I know this is really basic, sorry.

Comment: You gotta build the string. sprintf, stringstream, ect.

Comment: So I use: MessageBox(0, TEXT(sprintf("You have %s items", itemNum)), "title", 0);  ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a utility function to build a `std::string` from a `printf`-style format:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string build_string(const char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    size_t len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    std::vector<char> vec(len + 1);
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vsnprintf(vec.data(), len + 1, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    return std::string(vec.begin(), vec.end() - 1);
}
```

With this function in place, you can create arbitrary strings and pass pointers to their contents as downward-arguments:

```
MessageBoxA(0, build_string("You have %d items", item_count).c_str(), "title", 0);
```

It has the advantage of simplicity (several lines of code using only `stdio` without dependency on iostreams), and has no arbitrary limits on the size of string.

Comment: I cannot understand why this is the accepted answer for a C++ question. Adam Roosevelt's is arguably the correct answer.

Comment: But I like to use this way with va_list, it's better.

Comment: @Moo-Juice I fail to see what you think is wrong with the answer. It is correct, fast, robust, and solves the OP's problem, satisfying including the desired use of printf-style format strings (which are popular in C++ as much as in C). In addition to the above, it uses the C++ facilities such as STL vectors and strings to ensure safety and robustness, and has no arbitrary limits on string size. How is that answer "less correct" than another one?

Comment: The robustness is quite limited because it suffers from the type-insafety of `...`; e.g. on some implementations you can use this to print `std::string` but only if they're long enough (!) That's not what I call robust. Fast? Meh. The `%s` is interpreted at runtime, even though the correct type is known at compile time.

Comment: Fast compared to `stringstream` based solutions, which are (at least on several popular implementations) measurably and significantly slower — in some cases an order of magnitude — than a call to `snprintf`. Type-unsafety inherent to the `snprintf` format is obviously shared by any solution based on it.

Answer (score 8):

You have to build the string yourself.  In C++, this is typically done with `std::ostringstream`, e.g.:

```
#include <sstream>
...

std::ostringstream message;
message << "You have " << numItems << " items";
MessageBoxA(NULL, message.str().c_str(), "title", MB_OK);
```

In C, this is typically done with [`snprintf(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf):

```
#include <stdio.h>
...

char buffer[256];  // Make sure this is big enough
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "You have %d items", numItems);
MessageBoxA(NULL, buffer, "title", MB_OK);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll vote up within 9 minutes :) But imagine that I want to do the same in other cases, something with va_list would help?

Comment: +1, but I always find in these examples to show which includes should be included.  Inclusively.  Inclined to do so. :)

Comment: Since the OP is probably using Windows, if they are using MFC, the `CString` family of classes also has a `Format` function that behaves in a very similar fashion to the `sprintf` family.

Comment: @user2696223 See my answer for the va_list variant you're likely looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For MessageBoxA it is:

```
char szBuf[120];
snprintf(szBuf,120, "You have %s items",nItemCount);
MessageBoxA(0, szBuf, "title", 0);
```

It is ugly, but it will fit your need.

Comment: You're not passing snBuf to the Messagebox

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/format/doc/format.html).

In your example: `MessageBoxA(0, (boost::format("You have %1 items") % "title").c_str(), 0);`

One advantage is that you don't need to remember all those `%s` codes anymore, another is that you're no longer limited by the set of built-in flags.

The `( ).c_str()` is needed because `MessageBoxA` is a C interface, not C++, and `c_str()` converts a C++ string to a C string.